# How do I run an infinite loop in a thread using PySimpleGUI

Tags: user-interface, event-handling, infinite-loop, pysimplegui

I am trying to run a PySimpleGUI that would run nearly all day and has some data that is pulled every 5 minutes from an API. Below is some code to explain. I want to be able to also get user input while the thread is running (but it doenst need to return immediately)

```
def main_window():
    #skipping window layout
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        process_event(event, values)
    window.close()


def process_event(event, values):
    if event == 'Infinity Loop':
        threading.Thread(target=infinite_loop_function(window), daemon=True).start()

    elif event == 'Click':
        print("clicked!")

    elif event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
        exit(1)
    print('You entered ', values)

def infinite_loop_function():
    while(1):
        if (current_time > last_time_update + 5):
             #this updates every 5 minutes
             #need to receive UI input/accept other events between updates
```

Answer (score 0):

Example for you

[image]

```py
import time
from random import randint
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def the_thread(window):

    global duration

    time_start = time.time()
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if time.time()-time_start >= duration:
            time_start = time.time()
            data = (randint(0, 1000), randint(0, 1000))
            window.write_event_value('-THREAD-', data)

sg.theme("DarkBlue3")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

duration = 1

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Data Pulling\n", justification='center', key='-TITLE-')],
    [sg.Text("Data1"),
     sg.Text("", size=(7, 1), justification='right', background_color='green', key='-DATA1-'),
     sg.Text("Data2"),
     sg.Text("", size=(7, 1), justification='right', background_color='green', key='-DATA2-')],
    [sg.Text("Duration (second)"),
     sg.Input("", size=(4, 1), key="-DURATION-"),
     sg.Button("Set")],
    [sg.Button("Start")],
]

window = sg.Window('Data Pulling', layout, finalize=True)
window['-TITLE-'].expand(expand_x=True)
window['-DURATION-'].update(str(duration))
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, "Exit"):
        break
    elif event == "Set":
        try:
            duration = int(values["-DURATION-"])
        except:
            window['-DURATION-'].update(str(duration))
    elif event == "Start":
        threading.Thread(target=the_thread, args=(window,), daemon=True).start()
        window["Start"].update(disabled=True)
    elif event == "-THREAD-":
        data1, data2 = values[event]
        window['-DATA1-'].update(str(data1))
        window['-DATA2-'].update(str(data2))

    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

Comment: Do i need a write_event_value statement in the loop? In theory I just want to start the thread and then have it run indefinitely in the background while the UI still waits for other events and updates a few fields seperately. The other functions im running should run in the main event loop no problem since they do not take too much time.

Comment: Use method `window.write_event_value` only if you want to do something about GUI, like update data on GUI here.

Comment: Currently my threaded function has an infinite loop in it and causes the main window (UI) to be non-responsive. I don't need any of the information from the thread displayed in the window.

Comment: Maybe it can help, https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/4051, or demo script https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/tree/master/DemoPrograms

Comment: I ended up using a timeout in the read call and sticking what I needed updated before the read call. This works for my use-case. Thanks for the help